# how to get customer group name using customer id magento2

Tags: magento2

I am not able to get **Customer group name using customer id** in magento2.
i have customer group id but i didn't get group name.

```
<?php 
    $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',  $group_id);

    print_r($customer_data->getCustomerData());
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try below code :**

```
protected $_customerSession;

protected $_customerGroupCollection;

public function __construct(
    ....    
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $customerGroupCollection,
    ....
) {


    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_customerGroupCollection = $customerGroupCollection;

}

public function getCustomerGroup()
{
        echo $currentGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); //Get customer group Id , you have already this so directly get name
        $collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($currentGroupId); 
        echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have customer object and also i have customer group id 
and i want customer name using customer group id without session.
 i want any customer group name. i have my code with customer group id.

$customer_data->load($customer_id);
$group_id=$customer_data->getGroupId();
$collection = $this->_customerGroupCollection->load($group_id); 
 echo $collection->getCustomerGroupCode();//Get group name
 but i did'nt get customer group using my above code.

now how to use $group_id for get customer  group name using group id.

Answer (score 2):

> If you have customer data and know the customer group id then you can use **\Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface** and you won't need customer session.

```
public function __construct(
   ...
   \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
   ...
) {
   ...
   $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
}
```

> **Then in your function:**

```
$customerGroupId = $customerData->getGroupId();
$customerGroup = $this->groupRepository->getById($customerGroupId);
echo 'customer group name '.$customerGroup->getCode();
```